# In sencha touch 2, Pop the navigationView to root on tab changed

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have an application with Sencha touch 2.

I have 5 tabs(in my barpanel), and inside some of this tabs I have a navigation view.

I would like that when I selected a tab, automatically the navigation view is on the root windows.

Someone has a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could listen to the `activeitemchange` event of the tabpanel. If it fires you would pop `items.length-1` items from the navigation view.